# How to use echo in shell command from Makefile?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cygwin, mingw

I have a [GNU makefile](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile). It runs fine on Linux, Solaris and OS X. However, under Cygwin-32, Cygwin-64 and MinGW, it produces:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo 2.0.4(0.287/5/3) | egrep -i -c "fc22.i686"'
```

There is no Line 0; and the test for Fedora 22 actually occurs Line 73:

```
IS_FEDORA22_i686 = $(shell echo $(RELEASE) | $(EGREP) -i -c "fc22.i686")
```

What is going on with Cygwin and MinGW? More importantly, how can I fix it?

---

I know it sounds like a stretch, so here is a screen capture. The upper left is MinGW. The center is Cygwin-32. The lower right is Cygwin-64.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the shell is seeing the parentheses in `$RELEASE` outside of any quotes, so is trying to interpret them.  Two things to try: put double-quotes around the reference to `$(RELEASE)`, and use `:=` per [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors).  For example:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash.  #at the top of the makefile
IS_FEDORA22_i686 := $(shell echo "$(RELEASE)" | $(EGREP) -i -c "fc22.i686")
```

**Edit:** [uname](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname) output with switches like `-m` doesn't usually have any shell metacharacters.  The same problem could happen with any variable that did.  That's why it's useful to set `SHELL` in your makefile - if the user is running `csh`, you will have different problems than with `bash`.

Comment: If you have a test machine, then `git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git` A related question: why are the other variables, like `SYSTEM`, not causing problems?